# How to use Kiota MultiPart with IFormFileCollection

Tags: c#, swagger, .net-6.0, kiota

I am using Kiota to generate an HTTP client within a shared project among multiple solutions. Everything is functioning as expected, except for one specific use case related to a POST resource. The resource and command are defined as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromForm] CreateUserCommand command)
    => Ok(await _mediator.Send(command));
```

The CreateUserCommand includes an IFormFileCollection for attachments:

```
public class CreateUserCommand : IRequest< bool>
{

    public CreateUserCommand ()
    {
    }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public IFormFileCollection Attachements { get; set; } = new FormFileCollection();
  }
```

Kiota generates the following method signature:

```
    public async Task<Int32BooleanResultResponse?> PostAsync(MultipartBody body, Action<RequestBuilderPostRequestConfiguration>? requestConfiguration = default, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

Here is an example of how I attempted to construct the MultipartBody:
so in my request i need to send the user informations with attachements file, does any one knows how to do it, i did not find anything in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openapi/kiota/overview)

```
       var multipartBody = new MultipartBody();

        multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("email", "application/json", applyCommand.Email);
        multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("address", "application/json", applyCommand.Address);
        multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("firstName", "application/json", applyCommand.FirstName);
        multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("lastName", "application/json", applyCommand.LastName);
        multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("phone", "application/json", applyCommand.Phone);
```

Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly structure the request to send user information along with attachment files using Kiota? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you also share the OpenAPI description for the request body that asp.net generated please?

Comment: Hello baywet, we already discussed about the issue here https://github.com/microsoft/kiota/issues/3826

Comment: a ticket is already created for the documentation here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/openapi-docs/issues/49

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize you were the same person!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how one can send both the properties AND the attachments within the same request for this backend/scenario.

```cs
var multipartBody = new MultipartBody();
    
multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("Email", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", applyCommand.Email);
multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("Address", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", applyCommand.Address);
multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("FirstName", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", applyCommand.FirstName);
multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("LastName", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", applyCommand.LastName);
multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("Phone", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", applyCommand.Phone);
multipartBody.AddOrReplacePart("filename", "application/octet-stream", fileStream); // filename must be unique
```